# How to add a timestamp column in Hive at the time of external table creation

Tags: hive, timestamp, hdfs, external-tables

I have a csv file in hdfs and need to create a external table in Hive. I also need to add a extra column timestamp that should by default hold the value of record insert timestamp. I read that it is not possible in hive to set a default value like SQL Server.

How to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

in lower versions, looks like hive CURRENT_DATE is not available, hence you can use

```
select TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())) as timestamp;
```

In higher versions say hive 2.0, you can use :

```
select CURRENT_DATE as timestamp;
```